# Problemas con anclas en navegadores

Tags: javascript, html, css3, wordpress

Resulta que estoy creando una plantilla *WordPress* y tengo problemas para redireccionar a partes específicas de la zona, como la página principal. Quiero ir a [esta página](http://chronsult.com/es/nuestros-servicios/#metricas-y-recompensas), que obviamente por el ancla estoy que le indico que me mande a esa zona de la página pero no sé por qué en algunos navegadores como *Firefox* no funciona correctamente y no me manda al ancla que debería. ¿Hay forma de optimizarlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que veo de tu ejemplo, creo que es porque el contenido aun no esta cargado o no en su totalidad, lo que debes hacer es esperar a que la pagina cargue y entonces hacer el scroll.

en Jquery Seria algo como esto.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.location.hash) {
        $(document).scrollTop( $(window.location.hash).offset().top);
    }
});
```

Si cargas el contenido usando Ajax, entonces tienes que hacer el scroll despues de el ajax fue exitoso y pinte el contenido. O puedes poner un settimeout de unos segundos pero dependiendo de la conexión del usuario puede que llegue a fallar.

EDIT: Edito para que verifiques si tiene hash y si tiene lo redirija, puede que dependiendo si acepta o no más parámetros te toque manejar lo con expresiones regulares

Comment: Entonces tendria que poner esa funcion por cada link que se maneje con caja?, y agregarle esa funcion en un evento click al boton?